# Opening applications with random theme

Tags: bash, themes, gtk3

I'm using `Canvas` GTK theme and have all colors of that theme on my system.

I want to use one of those Canvas themes randomly each time I open an application.

I know I can use `env GTK_THEME` to open an application with different theme but the problem with that is the title bar is still the main theme on some applications like libre office, not the theme that I specified in `env GTK_THEME`.

Beside this problem, I don't know how to do this when every new application launch, so I wrote this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
theme_names=("Canvas" "Canvas-red" "Canvas-pink" "Canvas-indigo" "Canvas-blue" "Canvas-indigo" "Canvas-yellow")
theme_length=${#theme_names[@]}
rand_value=$(( $RANDOM % theme_length ))
theme_name=${theme_names[$rand_value]}
echo "$1 is opening with $theme_name theme\n"
echo "script is running: env GTK_THEME=$theme_name $1"
env GTK_THEME=$theme_name $1
```

and then I can run it with `./myscript.sh gedit` and the application can have random theme each time I run the script.

How can I apply this script globally? and is there anyway to solve title bar issue?

Comment: Well, you'd have to watch for new windows appearing, but then `GTK_THEME` has to be applied to each and every window individually which is not something you can do, and you can't account for every possible launcher that opens an application.

Comment: So short answer, I don't think it's possible to apply random theme to each window. Though if someone can make it work, I'd be pleasantly surprised